# Including a referenced parent entity's values in the child template variable list in jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I have been trying to use a template which prints out entity values from my model QA and also a couple of values from its parent environment's entity which has the model PQ. In particular, the code I have supplied works as is, but it does not allow me to include values from s such as s.name because s.name is not in qs. I have attempted to use the commented out line, for example (# qs["name"] = s.name) but I get the error "TypeError: 'Query' object does not support item assignment".

```
class MainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        s = PQ()
        s.name = "CCD1"
        s.owner = user
        s.put()
        q = QA()
        q.survey = s
        q.question = "If we dress up?"
        q.answers = [0, 0, 0]
        q.seqnum = float(100)
        q.put()
        qs = QA.all()
        # qs["name"] = s.name
        self.render_template('index.html',  {'qs': qs})
```

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this, please?

The following answer seems relevant, but is not quite the answer.

[how to display parent entity while looping through child entities in Jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100711/how-to-display-parent-entity-while-looping-through-child-entities-in-jinja2-temp)

(I have asked the same question on google groups but then remembered the recommendation to post question here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
template_values = {'qs': qs,
            'name': s.name
            }
self.render_template('index.html',  template_values )
```