# How to check if entity exist in gae datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to check datastore if entity kind "Kayit" exist to create new . 
my db.model class:

```
class Kayit(db.Model):
    url=db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

currently using this to check but it doesnt seem elegant

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        r_name="none"               
        q=db.Query(Kayit)    
        try:
            self.response.write(q[0].url)
        except:
            kay=Kayit(parent=_DefterKey(r_name),key_name='alibaba')
            kay.url="some url"                
            kay.put()
```

I guess we get the parent key with db.Key.from_path('Kayit', 1) . how can I use to check if it has entities?

Comment: Is there a reason you **must** use old crufty `db` rather than the vastly preferred, newer `ndb`? I'm so rusty on `db` that I'd need a long refresh cycle to help w/that -- I've used nothing but `ndb` for so many years!

Comment: @AlexMartelli as you can guess from my questions to you, because I'm totaly a newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was answered by:

[How to query parent entity from child entity in Google App Engine (Python) NDB/Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067624/how-to-query-parent-entity-from-child-entity-in-google-app-engine-python-ndb-d)

documented in in the cloud API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity

...and is shown in the python "Guestbook" google example:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore

Look at the stanza that goes:

```
 greetings_query = Greeting.query(
        ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
 greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)
```